# Can someone explain why to[i] = '\0' is correct?

Tags: arrays, c, string

It's a function that should copy a given string into another string. Can someone explain me why `to[i] = '\0'` is correct without `++` to `i` after the loop has stop and what `++` means before and after `i`.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void copyStringArr(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[] = "A string to be copied";
    char string2[250];

    copyStringArr(string2, string1);
    printf("%s\n", string2);
    
    return 0;
}

void copyStringArr(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; i++)
        to[i] = from[i];
    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What does your text-book or tutorial say? What about what they say don't you understand?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The name of the operator is "post-increment" operator. You can look up your learning material for that. As `i++` is only affecting the value *after* it was used, there is no point in using it if there is no access to `i` any more.

Comment: Hm... Actually that can be solved much more elegantly by using the pointers directly: `while(*from) { *to++ = *from++; } *to = 0;` – note that these pointers are just copies of those pointers passed to, so this code won't modify the original pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's copy a 2-char string (`"hi"`) *instruction* by *instruction* ..

```
// from = "hi"
// to = "HERE BE DRAGONS..." // garbage

i = 0;
from[0] != 0     // is true
to[0] = from[0]; // to = "hERE BE DRAGONS..."
i++              // i is 1 now
from[1] != 0     // is true
to[1] = from[1]; // to = "hiRE BE DRAGONS..."
i++              // i is 2 now
from[2] != 0     // is false, so exit loop
to[2] = 0;       // terminate string, don't care about i anymore
                 // to = "hi"; the DRAGONS (the initial garbage) are
                 // still in memory, you need "special tricks" to see them
```

Answer (score 0):

Because for loops are executed as:

- Execute once: `i = 0;`.
- Then loop:

  - Check `from[i] != '\0'`
  - Execute loop body.
  - Execute `i++`.

The last full lap of the loop executes `i++` and then the next `from[i] != '\0'` check yields true. That's where it stops and `i` was already incremented so that its value corresponds to the index of the null terminator.

---

You can illustrate it with this code that uses the comma operator to sneak in a printf at each of the mentioned steps:

```
for(int i=(printf("[i=0]\n"),0); 
    printf("[i<3] "), i<3; 
    printf("[i++]\n"), i++)
{
  printf("[loop body i: %d] ", i);
}
```

Output:

```
[i=0]
[i<3] [loop body i: 0] [i++]
[i<3] [loop body i: 1] [i++]
[i<3] [loop body i: 2] [i++]
[i<3]
```